# Set and Get sseions using thymleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have seen [this](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/05/spring-mvc-and-thymeleaf-how-to-acess-data-from-templates.html) ,and am trying to set a session in a page and the pass it to a method using a post request and print it.So here are the 3 steps:

**Step 1:** Set a session in the first page:

```
@RequestMapping(method=GET, path="/ShowRequestedPlantsInPO")    //PS5
  public String ShowRequestedPlantsInPO(Model model,HttpSession session){
    session.setAttribute("mySessionAttribute", "someValue");
    return "dashboard/orders/ShowPOs";
}
```

**Step 2:** Get the session in the page

```
<form style='float:left; padding:5px; height:0px' th:object="${p}"
  th:method="post"
  th:action="@{/dashboard/testSession/th:text=${session.mySessionAttribute} }"
>                       
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">
    Test Session
  </button>
</form>
```

As you can see, I have tried to access to my session using `th:text=${session.mySessionAttribute}`

**Step 3:**  Get the value of session in the target method of previous form:

```
@RequestMapping(method=POST, path="/testSession/{email:.+}")
public String testSession(@PathVariable("email") String email) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Invoice is sent to..................."+email);
  return "dashboard/orders/Invoice";
}
```

The problem is it does not print the session value **"SomeValue"**
the only thing it prints is:
  **th:text=${session.mySessionAttribute}**

Comment: @JB Nizet  Can you help me with this?

Comment: This syntax `th:action="@{/dashboard/testSession/th:text=${session.mySessionAttribute}` is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the Thymeleaf syntax slightly. Change the form tag `th:action` attribute to:

```
<form style='float:left; padding:5px; height:0px' th:object="${p}" th:method="post"
 th:action="@{'/dashboard/testSession/'+${session.mySessionAttribute} }">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">Test Session</button>
</form>
```